# How start a lot the same activities one by one

Tags: android, android-activity

I have not typical situation in my app. I have main activity, then I open activity A, from activity A I can open activity B, from activity B I can open activity A etc. 
I looked in Android monitor in this case and every time application memory was increased. App crashed, for example, in 150 activity's and 90mb memory. After this memory was clear and opened​ previous activity (A or B) and user can navigate back.

Can I prevent this issue? For example, use special intent flag or something else. Thanks a lot.

**Note** user can navigate back

Comment: was it the goal to open so many activities?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs this is our acceptance criteria :)

Comment: 150 activities? You should call finish() on that activity that is leaved or should put the attribute singleInstance into the manifest on the activity levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` when starting an `Activity`. This will move an existing instance of this `Activity` (if one already exists in the stack) to the front without creating a new instance of that `Activity`. If you do this beware that `onCreate()` will not be called on the instance a second time. Instead `onNewIntent()` will be called to deliver the `Intent` that was used to reorder it, and then `onResume()`.

This, however, will not solve your BACK problem. If you really want your user to be able to go BACK 150 times and be presented with the Activity stack in exact reverse order, you will need to solve this problem separately. To do this you can create the illusion of having 150 activities in the stack by maintaining your own stack of objects in a `public static` variable.Each object in the stack should contain enough data for you to recreate (or reorder) the appropriate `Activity` with the appropriate data.

Answer (score 1):

Use **singleTop** as an attribute of `<activity>` tag inside **AndroidManifest.xml** file list this:

> **singleTop** Activity instance could be created as many as we want. Only
>   difference is if there already is an Activity instance with the same
>   type at the top of stack in the caller Task, there would not be any
>   new Activity created, instead an Intent will be sent to an existed
>   Activity instance through **onNewIntent()** method.

There a good discussion regarding, [Understand Android Activity's launchMode: standard, singleTop, singleTask and singleInstance](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en)

Answer (score 0):

finish() can be called to kill (destroy) an Activity instance.
finish: [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)

You can also examine Lifecycle: [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)